# Dropped-in state with Html5

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I have found this snippet in html5:

```
<script>
    function drag(target, evt) {
        evt.dataTransfer.setData("Text", target.id);
    }
    function drop(target, evt) {
        var id = evt.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        target.appendChild(document.getElementById(id));
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
</script>

<img src="../#"  id="block1" ondragstart="drag(this, event)" alt="block1">
<img src="../#"  id="block2" ondragstart="drag(this, event)" alt="block2"><br/>

<div class="box" ondragover="return false" ondrop="drop(this, event)">
    <p>Box 1</p>
</div>
<div class="box" ondragover="return false" ondrop="drop(this, event)">
    <p>Bax 2</p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

How can I receive which block is in box1, in box2, etc. We can't differentiate both boxes there, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, give the boxes unique `id` attributes. Then, you can use the `target` parameter to the `drop()` function:

```
<div class="box" ondragover="return false" ondrop="drop(this, event)" id="box1">
    <p>Box 1</p>
</div>
<div class="box" ondragover="return false" ondrop="drop(this, event)" id="box2">
    <p>Box 2</p>
</div>
```

Then you can use the value `target.id` to distinguish between the two divs.

Also, you can use the `target` parameter of the `drag()` function to get the `id` attribute of the block being dragged, assuming the blocks have `id` attributes assigned to them.

Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vUm2v/).

Lots of information on drag-and-drop for HTML5 here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dnd.html#dnd